# Get independent parameter string from Dataflow Pipeline Options

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to trigger a Google Dataflow job from Airflow and need help in sending a string from Airflow as parameter which could be read in Dataflow and used as an independent string.

Here´s the code for my `DataflowTemplateOperator` which sends the parameter named `secretCode`:

```
        DataflowTemplateOperator(
            task_id=TASK_ID,
            job_name=JOB_NAME,
            template=TEMPLATE_PATH,
            parameters={
                "secretCode": "123456"
            },
            dag=dag
        )
```

I want to read the `secretCode` from `PipelineOptions` as `String` as send to the following `ParDo` but I don´t know how to do that. The code does not have anything to do with the input and output of the `ParDo` class. I just want to write the code to BigQuery.

```
    val dataToTableRow: PCollection<TableRow> = myCustomDataStructure.apply(
        "transform my data to table row",
        ParDo.of(DataToTableRow())
    )
```

I want to write the secret code returned from the `PipelineOptions` to BigQuery as I show in the code below but I don´t know how to get there:

```
   class DataToTableRow : DoFn<myCustomDataStructure, TableRow>() { 
      @ProcessElement
      fun processElement(@Element myData: myCustomDataStructure, outputReceiver: OutputReceiver<TableRow>) {
          outputReceiver.output(getTableRow(myData))
      }

      private fun getTableRow(myData: myCustomDataStructure): TableRow {
          return TableRow().set("ID", myData.id)
                           .set("SecretCode", secretCode)
      }
   }
```

I would appreciate some help regarding how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own interface that extends PipelineOptions and set your parameter here.

```
  public interface SecretOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    String getSecretCode();
    void setSecretCode(String secretCode);
  }
```

And then, register your interface on your Pipeline like this :

```
PipelineOptionsFactory.register(SecretOptions.class);
SecretOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
        .withValidation()
        .as(SecretOptions.class);
```

Then you'll be able to access to your parameter anywhere on your pipeline using `options.getSecretCode();`

More informations on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options)